# XML output of all user changes from history

Tags: openstreetmap

is there an xml url to extract a list of all changes made by a user? I am originally after just the bounds and the changeset id. I have tried the history function in the ID editor but having 4000 change sets it's time consuming and difficult to find the change set I am after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [OSM API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) to [retrieve changesets of a specific user](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Query%3a_GET_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2Fchangesets). It also supports additional parameters like *bbox* and *time*.